# Is using a string constant in C++ ternary operator an invalid use of non-lvalue array?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I have code which checks a condition using the ternary operator and then either returns a pointer to a c-string constant or throws an exception.

Strangely, the compilation only fails when I `throw` from one path of the ternary operator.  If I put a string constant on both sides everything compiles.

```
// this line gives no compilation error
auto str = condition ? "foo" : "bar";

// this line gives "error: invalid use of non-lvalue array"
auto str = condition ? "foo" : throw std::runtime_error{"bad"};
```

This problem has started showing up in gcc 9.1.  I have used lines with both of the above patterns for many years and they compile without warning in clang and earlier versions of gcc.

Is the above pattern actually invalid, or is this a compiler bug in gcc 9.1?

Comment: I think it is pretty obvious that using string literal is not an issue, but throwing exception is. So answer to the subject is no, but actual question is it legal to throw exception in one branch of ternary.

Comment: @Slava the thing is that with string literals it [doesn't work](https://godbolt.org/z/lPc87t), but with `int`s, [it does](https://godbolt.org/z/1nRiss). I suspect a compiler bug, though, since I agree that the problem probably lies in `throw`ing from conditional operator itself.

Comment: @Fureeish I see, but when there are 2 string literals it works as well as shown by OP, so still issue is not string literal itself, but its combination with throwing exception. So subject is misleading IMHO.

Comment: The type of `"foo"` is `const char[4]`, and the compiler is apparently using this as the type for `str`, then wanting to copy the value from one array to another.  I don't (yet) know if this is a bug, or something from a change in the language (or interpretation of the language), but as a workaround you can cast `"foo"` to a `const char *`.  `(const char *) "foo"`.

Comment: Interestingly cppreference.com uses almost the exact line I'm having trouble with as an example (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other).

Comment: I'm leaning towards this must be a compiler bug.  The standard says "If either the second or third operand is a throw expression the result is of the type and value category of the other".  This means that the overall expression must have the same type and value as `"foo"`.  There is no conversion specified by the standard at this point so no opportunity for an invalid use of a non-lvalue.

Comment: @rici No, it's not `auto`.  The problem persists if changing to `char const*`: https://godbolt.org/z/8agVgJ

Comment: This code compiles [fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JgpyassoLiucRQi3) with clang.  Probably a bug.

Comment: @marack, yeah I just did that test. Sorry.

Comment: Here's an even stranger manifestation: casting the entire conditional to a char* causes the program to be discarded, presumably as Undefined Behaviour. (Including flagging a textually used variable as unused because, presumably, the use has been discarded). https://godbolt.org/z/_j_f6W

Comment: As a workaround, does `auto str = condition ? "foo" : ((void)(throw std::runtime_error{"bad"}), "nothing to see here, move along, move along");` get past it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right.  The ternary operator propagates the type and value category of one operand if the other is a throw-expression.  The conditional-expression is an lvalue of type `const char[4]`.  `auto` then deduces `const char*`.  There is no "invalid use of non-lvalue array" here.

Also, the code compiles [fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JgpyassoLiucRQi3) with clang.  I'd say that this is a bug with GCC.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  I'm raising it as a bug with the GCC devs.